# Distributed Transactions for Server-to-Server Communication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just need someone confirm what I am thinking.
If i have 2 sql servers and I have procedure that updates 2 tables, 
each table in a diffrent database.
If i want to protect the transaction (acid) i need to turn on this checkbox.
M i wrire?

If I'm wrong , cam someone  please explain me what is 
'Require Distributed Transactions for Server-to-Server Communication' and give me example.

Comment: i ment if i need to mark the 'Require Distributed Transactions for Server-to-Server Communication' check box.
if not what this checkbox do?

Comment: Yes, Distributed transaction is responsible for maintaining ACID property if multiple systems are involved.

Comment: Do you mean the service doesn not start automatically in services.msc ?

Comment: @eladavraham: DTC is slow (and I mean slow), causing locking issues and timeouts.  DTC suffers from unusual network requirements.  Turning on DTC causes things that work just fine to start failing.  Sane persons avoid DTC, which is why it is turned off by default.

Comment: i mean why this check box doenst mark by defualt?